# php while mysql fetch array , update each 10 results at once ,

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

I try to use while mysql fetch array to get all data from table then update .
I use my code to do that and it working right but one by one.
I need to update each 10 results at the same time then other 10 until end.

my code is

```
$get_urls = mysql_query("select * from urls where (status = 'active') ORDER BY number ASC");
    while($show_url = mysql_fetch_array($get_urls, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $urlid = $show_url['0'];

    $edit_urls = "UPDATE urls SET online = 'yes' WHERE urlid = '$urlid'";
    mysql_query($edit_urls);

    }
    mysql_free_result($get_urls);
```

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Could you please revise your grammar and clarify your question?

Comment: sorry for my poor english language . 
results will be about 3000 rows
normally it update one after one row.
I need to update every 10 rows together on one time then next 10 rows etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array` & `implode` to achieve this

```
$array = array();
$get_urls = mysql_query("select * from urls where (status = 'active') ORDER BY number ASC");
    while($show_url = mysql_fetch_array($get_urls, MYSQL_NUM))
       $array[] = $show_url['0'];

$edit_urls = "UPDATE urls SET online = 'yes' WHERE urlid IN (".implode(',',$array).")";
    mysql_query($edit_urls);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `array_chunk`

```
$input_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 2));
//output  
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => a
        [1] => b
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => c
        [1] => d
    )
)

array_chunk($data,10);
foreach ($data as $key => $value){
  // excute your sql query update.
```

Hope this help.